# Как получить список индексов повторяющихся элементов массива?

Tags: python, массивы

Создан массив размерностью 100 со случайными числами от 0 до 100.
Так же задаются несколько случайных чисел для поиска.
Нужно узнать количество повторений числа и с каким индексом оно было найдено.
Количество повторений я смог найти через **count()**, но с индексами возникла проблема так как **index()** выдает только первый индекс искомого числа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно завести словарь с ключами из чисел, каждый из которых будет хранить вложенный словарь с количеством найденных экземпляров и их индексами:

```
from random import randint
arr = list( map(lambda _: randint(0, 101), range(100)) )

####

data = {}

for index, num in enumerate(arr):
    if( not num in data ):
        data[num] = { "qty": 1, "indexes": [index] }
        continue
    
    data[num]["qty"] += 1
    data[num]["indexes"].append(index)


print( data )
```